# How to determine that there is date in the string or not with different date format?

Tags: c#, regex, date

I have a need of checking whether there is the date in the string or not.

```
FUTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY 0 -- There is date in the string.

FUTIDX MINIFTY 30 Jul 2009 -- There is date in the string.

FUTSTK ONGC 27 Mar 2008 -- There is date in the string.
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: You have completely changed the question from it's original. Now my answer has absolutely nothing to do with your question. You should have simply written a new question.

Comment: @dboarman,Sorry,but as I got a regex that works for the date 26 FEB 2009 but not working with 26FEB2009 so I had changed the question. And still your answer is very useful to me.

Comment: thank you for rolling back your question...

Comment: you have (accepted my answer). Didn't want you to think I was upset at you for changing the question. I have submitted a feature request at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/alert-that-question-has-been-edited-or-re-tagged  based on this event. It's all good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @danish is telling you is that you will need to try out RegEx (or regular expressions). There are tons of sites out there - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx); [Practical Parsing](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/articles/6946.aspx); [Learn Regular Expressions](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx) - just to name a few.

If you are expecting your date in only 2 specific formats, then we only have 2 patterns that we would need to match. Your example data:

> FUTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY 0 -- There is date in the string.
>
> FUTIDX MINIFTY 30 Jul 2009 -- There is date in the string.
>
> FUTSTK ONGC 27 Mar 2008 -- There is date in the string.

provides us with 2 patterns:

1. `ddMMMyyyy`
2. `dd Mmm yyyy`

The example below will only look for a month in the short form. This should be enough to help you get going.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace regexmonthtest
{
    class MainClass
    {

            // in your class, define 2 string patterns
        static string pattern = @"(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)";

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (HasDate("FUTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY 0"));
            Console.WriteLine (HasDate("FUTSTK MINIFTY 30 Jul 2009"));
            Console.WriteLine (HasDate("FUTIDX 26api1234 NIFTY 0"));
        }


        public static bool HasDate (string textIn)
        {
            textIn = textIn.ToLower();
            Console.Write(textIn + '\t');

            return (Regex.Match(textIn, pattern).Success);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

> futidx 26feb2009 nifty 0  True
>   futstk minifty 30 jul 2009    True
>   futidx 26api1234 nifty 0  False

Answer (score 0):

What are all the formats you are supporting? Depending on that you will need a parser or maybe a regular expression (depending on the formats) to get the date out.

Edit: So it always will be DD MON YYYY or DDMONYYYY. Just have a regular expression to filter this part out from string and it would work.

Check [this](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View653502BD-00B7-4012-9786-F941208F5F0C.htm) expression. A bit of modifications and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the DateTime.TryParse() Method. But before you need to clean your string from the trash characters.

Another way is to write your own parser with custom rules of expressions.

Comment: @Harikrishna: I think he means removing everything but the date itself. But, if you were able to do that, then I don't think you would be asking your question.